# Tricky XML Manipulation: Create an element out of its own and other sibling's data

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have this replicate scenario my XML document below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Home>
   <Kitchen>
      <Pantry>
         <Ingredients>
            <Name>Tomato</Name>
            <ID>1</Price_ID>
            <Name>Tomato</Name>
            <Income>Sales</Income>  // replace the <Income> element with its value <Sales>
            <Cost>Materials</Cost>
            <Price>100</Price>      // the value for new <Sales> element shall be this <Price> value
          </Ingredients>
          //.. and thousands more sets of ingredients
       </Pantry>
    </Kitchen>
</Home>
//.. and thousands more sets of ingredients
```

And I want to restructure it in the following manner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Home>
   <Kitchen>
      <Pantry>
         <Ingredients>
            <Name>Tomato</Name>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <Name>Tomato</Name>
            <Sales>100</Sales>      // the <Income> was replaced by its value and the value was taken from the <Price> element that was deleted also
            <Cost>Materials</Cost>           
          </Ingredients>
          //.. and thousands more sets of ingredients
       </Pantry>
    </Kitchen>
</Home>
```

I'm still trying to figure out how I'm going to do this. I will appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Xml Ling :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication37
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> ingredients = doc.Descendants("Ingredients").ToList();

            foreach (XElement ingredient in ingredients)
            {

                XElement xIncome = ingredient.Element("Income");
                XElement xPrice = ingredient.Element("Price");
                xIncome.ReplaceWith(new XElement("Sales", (string)xPrice));
                xPrice.Remove();
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am actually incorporating this now with my code. I am surprised by your approach. New learning to me. I'll be with you in a while.

Comment: What's the `ToList` for? Also I think you want `xIncome.ReplaceWith(new XElement("Sales", xPrice.value));`

Comment: @Charlieface : using value will cause an exception if null.  Cast to string is better.  You do not get the exception when null.

Comment: Then use `xPrice?.Value` to be fair I don't think it makes any difference, just might be more obvious it's only returning the inner text not the whole node

Comment: @jdweng I think @Charlieface is right. I am actually looking for the `xPrice?.Value` but overall, it works perfectly fine with my need. Thanks so much!

Comment: Charlie says it doesn't matter and my preference is to not use value because of the exception it creates.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly create a `Class` for the new Model

```
public class NewIngredients 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public decimal Sales { get; set; }
   public string Cost{ get; set; }
}
```

Presuming the Xml Document is in a file called `Kitchen.xml`

```
XElement Kitchen = XElement.Load(@"Kitchen.xml");
```

then use `Linq to Xml` to create your new model from the old something like this (**Note** probably need to check for nulls etc)

```
var newIngredients = Kitchen.Descendants("Ingredients").Select(x => new NewIngredients
{
  Id = int.Parse(x.Element("ID").Value),
  Name = x.Element("Name").Value,
  Sales = decimal.Parse(x.Element("Price").Value)
  Cost = x.Element("Cost").Value
});
```

Convert back to xml if needed

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(newIngredients.First().GetType());
serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, newIngredients.First()); //Printed to console but could move to file if needed
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to present your solution but I find jdweng more closer to what I need, at least to me. Cheers!